# How to get the object data in a proper way react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need help in here. I am confused how to get the object data in a proper way.
When **console.log(response.data.Data)**
My data looks like this :

```
Object {
  "2014": Object {
    "1": "3.385",
    "10": "-0.191",
    "11": "0.383",
    "12": "0.191",
    "2": "3.023",
    "3": "3.667",
    "4": "3.774",
    "5": "-2.045",
    "6": "2.088",
    "7": "5.455",
    "8": "-3.448",
    "9": "16.741",
  },
  "2015": Object {
    "1": "1.905",
    "10": "5.092",
    "11": "-4.070",
    "12": "7.475",
    "2": "5.421",
    "3": "5.142",
    "4": "-9.106",
    "5": "4.824",
    "6": "-4.425",
    "7": "-2.963",
    "8": "-1.527",
    "9": "-4.845",
  },
  "2016": Object {
    "1": "-1.504",
    "10": "-1.115",
    "11": "-7.891",
    "12": "8.392",
    "2": "2.863",
    "3": "-1.299",
    "4": "-1.880",
    "5": "-0.383",
    "6": "2.500",
    "7": "8.443",
    "8": "4.152",
    "9": "4.319",
  }
}
```

I cannot use **console.log(response.data.Data.2014)** or **console.log(response.data.Data.object)**.

I want to get the year and the month object data. How do I get this object data ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```js
const data =  {
  "2014":  {
    "1": "3.385",
    "10": "-0.191",
    "11": "0.383",
    "12": "0.191",
    "2": "3.023",
    "3": "3.667",
    "4": "3.774",
    "5": "-2.045",
    "6": "2.088",
    "7": "5.455",
    "8": "-3.448",
    "9": "16.741",
  },
  "2015":  {
    "1": "1.905",
    "10": "5.092",
    "11": "-4.070",
    "12": "7.475",
    "2": "5.421",
    "3": "5.142",
    "4": "-9.106",
    "5": "4.824",
    "6": "-4.425",
    "7": "-2.963",
    "8": "-1.527",
    "9": "-4.845",
  },
  "2016":  {
    "1": "-1.504",
    "10": "-1.115",
    "11": "-7.891",
    "12": "8.392",
    "2": "2.863",
    "3": "-1.299",
    "4": "-1.880",
    "5": "-0.383",
    "6": "2.500",
    "7": "8.443",
    "8": "4.152",
    "9": "4.319",
  }
}



for (const year in data) {
  console.log(`${year}: ${data[year]}`);
  for (const month in data[year]) {
    console.log(`${month}: ${data[year][month]}`);
  }
}
```

and here is the document for it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: this one look easier

Answer (score 1):

If we look at your object you are using an integer as the key. Though you have converted your integer to be a string still you can't use it as `data.2014`. You have to use `data["2014"]`.

✔ The data object's key name will only work as `data.key` when your object will look like this:

```js
const data = {
   key: "Value"
}
```

or

```js
const data = {
   key2022: "Value"
}
```

✘ But it will not work when you use integer before in the key or you use an only integer to name your key and you need to use `data["key"]`:

```js
const data = {
   "1key": "Value"
}
```

or

```js
const data = {
   "1234": "Value"
}
```

✔ So, If you want to get the value you have to use this code and try to use `data["key"]` instead of `data.key` for your object.

```js
const data =  {
  "2014":  {
    "1": "3.385",
    "10": "-0.191",
    "11": "0.383",
    "12": "0.191",
    "2": "3.023",
    "3": "3.667",
    "4": "3.774",
    "5": "-2.045",
    "6": "2.088",
    "7": "5.455",
    "8": "-3.448",
    "9": "16.741",
  },
  "2015":  {
    "1": "1.905",
    "10": "5.092",
    "11": "-4.070",
    "12": "7.475",
    "2": "5.421",
    "3": "5.142",
    "4": "-9.106",
    "5": "4.824",
    "6": "-4.425",
    "7": "-2.963",
    "8": "-1.527",
    "9": "-4.845",
  },
  "2016":  {
    "1": "-1.504",
    "10": "-1.115",
    "11": "-7.891",
    "12": "8.392",
    "2": "2.863",
    "3": "-1.299",
    "4": "-1.880",
    "5": "-0.383",
    "6": "2.500",
    "7": "8.443",
    "8": "4.152",
    "9": "4.319",
  }
}



// To access the object of specific year use data["year"]
console.log(data["2014"])

// To access the value of specific month use data["year"]["month"]
console.log(data["2014"]["2"])
```

Comment: is it possible to do looping in this case ? I want to loop the response

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But you have to nest your loop. For example, you have to use a `.forEach()` to get the year's Object. And under that `.forEach` you have to run a `for` loop that's count starts from  1 and breaks when the value is 13

Comment: And to get years using forEach you can use the `loDash`. Please refer [LoDash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#forEach) if you want to learn more about it

Comment: i don't know how to use LoDash

Comment: Then you can either read their docs by clicking on the link or you can use regular `forEach` instead of loDash's `_.forEach`